# sticky nav bar scroll up doesnt return "else" function not removing class

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, navbar, nav

My nav bar works on scroll down but doesn't stop at original position on scroll up. I saw one other post addressing a similar issue however I was unable to apply it in a way to correct my issue, granted I am VERY new to this. Originally the nav bar did not work at all but through a lot of reading here on stackoverflow I was able to get it half running. Hopefully you guys can fix me lol, either way THANKS ahead of time for reading.

Applicable CSS-

```
nav {
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #e7ecf2;
  }  
  .nav-placeholder {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
  .fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .fixed .nav-inner {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
  }
```

Applicable JQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navOFFset = $("nav").offset().top;
  $("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
  $(".nav-placeholder").height($("nav").outerHeight());
  $("nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos=$(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos => navOffset) {
   $("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      $("nav").removeClass("fixed");

    }
  });
});
```

applicable HTML-

```
<nav class="row wrapme container-fluid"><div class="nav-placeholder">
     <div class="nav-inner"><div class="col-sm-3">
  <button class="btn btn-block target">About Me</button></div>
       <div class="col-sm-3"> <button class="btn btn-block target" id="target2">Portfolio</button></div>
       <div class="col-sm-3"> <button class="btn btn-block target" id="target3">Contact</button></div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"><button class="btn btn-block target" id="target3">Links</button></div>
       </div> </div></nav>
```

Comment: please paste your html as well.

Comment: no problem, edited. Thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/davidwhitten85/pen/rzwBWE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done a minor change in the logic. If scrollPos = navOffset then "fixed" class should be removed.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos=$(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos > 0) {//change removed = and navPosition param
   $("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      $("nav").removeClass("fixed");

    }
  });
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: okay attempted = removal but that halted the function altogether menu is now unaffected by $

Comment: apology missed one more change , now updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much. that worked perfectly. hopefully this will help someone else as well. learning=hey is some $ abc's now tackle this project lol. I assume the navPosition param was unneeded and had to do with a something outta the original code perhaps? as this was from another persons question on the topic on stack flow as well.